# GET and POST appear to be allowed regardless specification in the builder's WithMethods(..)

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

In my *StartUp.cs* I have the following setup for CORS.

```
services.AddCors(_ => _.AddPolicy("LocalDev", __ => __
  .AllowAnyOrigin()
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
));
```

It works as expected. However, I noticed that removing *GET* and *POST* doesn't seems to affect the funtionality. Removing *PUT* or *DELETE* has effect, though. I'm confused by this.

Is it the case that the methods for getting and posting enjoy a special status while the others are required to be explicitly provided? I haven't found any references on that in [MSDN for the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withmethods?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Cors_Infrastructure_CorsPolicyBuilder_WithMethods_System_String___).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.WithMethods` affects `GET`/`POST` requests only when they trigger a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request — basically, any `GET` or `POST` that includes custom request headers. If a `GET` or `POST` *doesn’t* include any custom request headers, then it won’t trigger a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request, and so it will be allowed regardless of what the `.WithMethods` setting is.

In CORS protocol terms, `.WithMethods` sets the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header value, which browsers only consult for responses to a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests.

For requests that do trigger a CORS preflight, an intersection of  conditions is required; i.e., the request must have both the right origin and the right method. But for requests that *don’t* trigger a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, there is by definition no “right” method — because in that case, any `Access-Control-Allow-Method` header is irrelevant and ignored. Or maybe rather, conceptually, it’s more clear to just say that there’s a hard-coded list of “right” methods: the set of [CORS-safelisted methods](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-method.) — `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST` — defined in the Fetch spec.

Answer (score 2):

> .WithMethods affects GET/POST requests only when they trigger a CORS preflight OPTIONS request — basically, any GET or POST that includes custom request headers.

- this is incorrect, even with a custom header, a POST+Preflight request works having .WithMethods("GET")

Answer (score 1):

I would test a couple of requests to the API and check the **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** header. That's the actual logic that allows/restricts any HTTP methods to reach your API.

If the header does contain **GET**, even though you didn't specify it in your list of allowed HTTP verbs, we are looking at a .NET Core bug and I think you should log it at https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues

Comment: Given how fundamental the methods *GET* and *POST* are, I doubt very intensely that I've found a bug, hehe. Are you able to reproduce the behavior on your system?

Comment: To elaborate on my findings. When I execute a *DELETE*, I see the preflight's *OPTIONS* in the network tab and the three *allow* headers where the one for methods states *PUT* and *DELETE* as supposed to (no *GET*). But when I run a *GET* request, I still get the data but there's nothing in the response headers about the allowed methods. It confuses me...

Comment: That does seem weird.. are you sending the _GET_ request the same way you're sending the _PUT_ or _DELETE_ one?

Comment: The same'ish way - from Swagger. They differ because it's different methods, of course. But other than that, no. I execute them from the same location etc.